# mongodb pyspark connector set up

Tags: mongodb

i have followed the link here to install, build is succesful but I cannot find the connector.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/intca2.tweetsIntca2") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/intca2.tweetsIntca2") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.2') \
.getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o592.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource

the connector was downloaded and built here
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark#please-see-the-downloading-instructions-for-information-on-getting-and-using-the-mongodb-spark-connector

I Am using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```py
df = spark.read.format("mongodb").load()
```

Then, you have to tell pyspark where to find the mongo libs, e.g.

```sh
/usr/local/bin/spark-submit --jars $HOME/java/lib/mongo-spark-connector-10.0.0.jar,$HOME/java/lib/mongodb-driver-sync-4.3.2.jar,$HOME/java/lib/mongodb-driver-core-4.3.2.jar,$HOME/java/lib/bson-4.3.2.jar mongo_spark1.py
```

Comment: thank you, I move the jar files to /usr/local/spark/jars , how would I explicity use them here?

Comment: Just change the comma separated list to point to where your jars live.   The key thing is to include BOTH the `mongo-spark-connector` jar AND the base mongo Java driver libs (mongodb-driver-sync, mongodb-driver-core, and bson).

Comment: thanks, I have added all with the url they live at which is spark/jars. unfortunately when i call the read function i am getting noClassDef Found error could not initliase class com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector

Comment: ?   There is no such class in the src distribution; com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector is a directory in  which we find `MongoTableProvider.java` and bunch of subdirs.   Try taking things out of the spark session builder `.config()` and move them to the `--jars` arg on the `spark-submit` command line.   I think it is just not finding all the jars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running pyspark in local mode.

- Mongodb version 4
- Spark version 3.2.1

I download all needed jars in one folder(*path_to_jars*) and add it to spark config

```
bson-4.7.0.jar
mongodb-driver-legacy-4.7.0.jar
mongo-spark-connector-10.0.3.jar
mongodb-driver-core-4.7.0.jar
mongodb-driver-sync-4.7.0.jar
```

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

url = 'mongodb://id:port/Database.collection'
spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .master('local[*]')
         .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath','path_to_jars/*')
         .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri",url)
         .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", url)
         .getOrCreate()
         )
df = spark.read.format("mongodb").load()
```